# What is a simple way to get the email subject

Tags: python

The following may not be elegant, but it works for me and saves the email text to a text file. I would like the text file to have the name contained in the email subject, which looks like this 'studentnumber, week number'.

So, I want to change file = 'email' + str(msgNum) + '.txt' to file = email_subject

How can I integrate that in this loop?

```
for msgNum in unseenMessages:
        file = 'email' + str(msgNum) + '.txt'
        theFile = open(pathToFiles + file, 'w')
        rawMessage = server.fetch(unseenMessages, ['BODY[]', 'FLAGS'])
        message = pyzmail.PyzMessage.factory(rawMessage[msgNum][b'BODY[]'])
        text = message.text_part.get_payload().decode(message.text_part.charset)
        #textCut = text.split()
        #saveText = ''.join(textCut)
        saveText = text.rstrip()
        theFile.write(saveText)
        theFile.close()
        server.set_flags(msgNum, '\Seen', silent=False) # Mark them as seen
        print('Email UID ' + str(msgNum) + 'saved and marked SEEN')
```

I can get the subject like this using 'from imapclient import IMAPClient':

```
messages = server.search('UNSEEN')
    for uid, message_data in server.fetch(messages, 'RFC822').items():
        email_message = email.message_from_bytes(message_data[b'RFC822'])
        print(uid, email_message.get('From'), email_message.get('Subject'))
```

but I can't figure out how to integrate that in my loop.

I tried:

```
message = server.fetch([178], 'RFC822').items()
```

This gets the whole message I believe. The subject is in there, but I can't see how to extract it

Comment: I would do a `dir(email_message)`, see what that exposes. There is a chance the body of the email can be extracted much like `From` and `Subject`.

Comment: Could you post some example of the email message?, is it an object or plain text? if its an object, what methods are available?

Answer (score 0):

The emails are just answers to multiple choice questions. I tidy up the text after saving and then compare with the answer key. Here is an example text:

> 1825010301,A,B,A,A,A,C,H,G,A,C,F,D,G,D,E,G,H,H,C,A,A,B,A,A,C,B,C,D,A,E,J,G,H,F,I
>
> 发自我的iPhone

I've fudged a kind of solution, again, not elegant, but I found this works. If you can improve on it, I'd be happy, I'm no coder!! This just saves the text to my laptop, then I can analyse it at leisure.

```
for uid, message_data in server.fetch(unseenMessages, 'RFC822').items():
        email_message = email.message_from_bytes(message_data[b'RFC822'])
        print(email_message.get('Subject'))
        messageSubject = email_message.get('Subject')
        file = messageSubject + '.txt'
        theFile = open(pathToFiles + file, 'w')
        rawMessage = server.fetch(unseenMessages, ['BODY[]', 'FLAGS'])
        message = pyzmail.PyzMessage.factory(rawMessage[uid][b'BODY[]'])
        text = message.text_part.get_payload().decode(message.text_part.charset)
        saveText = text.rstrip()
        theFile.write(saveText)
        theFile.close()
        #server.set_flags(msgNum, '\Seen', silent=False) # Mark them as seen
        print('Email UID ' + str(uid) + 'saved and marked SEEN')
```